# In Google Chrome on MacOS, can you suppress sending your client certificate to a website for debugging purposes?

Tags: google-chrome, security, authentication, certificate, client-certificates

I'm debugging requests to a web application. The app automatically logs me in every time, as Chrome sends my client certificate and I am recognized by it. However, I need to log in as a different user. Unfortunately, when I log out, the app automatically logs me in again immediately, as it recognizes my client certificate.

Therefore, I want to temporarily disable sending my client certificate when establishing the secure connection. Is there a setting in Chrome debugger or an extension or a setting in the OS settings? I could not find anything. Also Googling did not help.

Comment: When using a private/incognito window, Chrome should not send your client certificate.

Comment: Hm, I tried using incognito mode. Still, I'm getting logged in automatically. To be honest, I'm not sure what mechanisms the web app uses to log me in. I was assuming it is the client cert. Could it be something else? 
I can rule out cookies and local storage - I cleared both in the "Application" tab of the developer tools.

Comment: Try using firefox. It ignores whatever OS certificates you might have installed, as it has its own trust store.